# Como usar o virtualenv para gerenciar as dependências duma aplicação Python?

Tags: python, dependências

Preciso gerenciar as dependências de uma aplicação `Python` que estou desenvolvendo, de maneira que seja fácil para os outros desenvolvedores da equipe consigam trabalhar no projeto utilizando as mesmas versões dos pacotes que estou usando.

Consigo fazer isso com o [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org)? Como?

Comment: @downvoter: se importa em comentar?

Comment: Não fui eu que votei contra, mas talvez seja porque a questão é um tanto ampla.

Comment: Hmmm... Será? Ampla em que sentido? Achei que "Como usar virtualenv para gerenciar dependëncias" seria específico o suficiente. De qualquer forma, editei a pergunta tentando esclarecer. Tem alguma sugestão para melhorá-la?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

O [virtualenv][1] monta um ambiente Python "virtual", armazenando todas as dependências em um diretório.

Pessoalmente, eu gosto de usar o [virtualenvwrapper][2], que é um conjunto de scripts que facilitam um pouco a mecânica de criar esses ambientes.

Os passos para montar um ambiente virtual no Ubuntu com o virtualenvwrapper são:

1. Instale o virtualenvwrapper:

   `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`

   `echo source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh >> ~/.bashrc`
2. Crie um diretório onde ficarão seus ambientes virtuais:

   `mkdir ~/.virtualenvs`
3. Configure a variável de ambiente WORKON_HOME do virtualenvwrapper no `~/.bashrc`:

   `echo 'export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs' >> ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc`
4. Está pronta a configuração do virtualenvwrapper. Crie um novo ambiente virtual, com um nome fácil de digitar:

   `mkvirtualenv web`
5. Esse comando vai criar um ambiente com o nome *web* e ativá-lo, indicando o nome do ambiente no prompt do shell -- vai ficar algo parecido com *(web) [user@host] $*. Você pode sair do ambiente a qualquer momento usando o comando `deactivate` e voltar a trabalhar nele com o comando `workon web`.

Dentro do ambiente, você pode instalar as dependências necessárias usando o `pip`, que vai instalar apenas dentro do ambiente, exemplo para uma aplicação [Flask][3]:

```
pip install flask
```

Feita a instalação, você pode criar um arquivo com a lista das dependências usando:

```
pip freeze -l > requirements.txt
```

Isso vai gerar um arquivo requirements.txt com um conteúdo semelhante a:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
Werkzeug==0.9.4
itsdangerous==0.23
```

E é isso! Agora, quando outro desenvolvedor quiser se certificar de estar usando as mesmas dependências que você, ele precisa criar um virtualenv também, e instalar as dependências a partir desse mesmo arquivo, usando o comando:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Leia mais:**

http://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/virtualenv-ambientes-virtuais-para-desenvolvimento/
[1]: http://www.virtualenv.org
[2]: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org
[3]: http://flask.pocoo.org