# Modulos em Python linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

Estou tendo alguns problemas para instalar módulos no meu python em linux. Atualmente estou usando o python 2.7.10, a maioria dos módulos eu utilizo o pip para instalar, porém quando eu executo o python 2.7.10 e importo meu modulo ele diz que não encontrou, porém se eu utilizar a versão 2.7.6 (/usr/bin/python2.7) eles funcionam, parece que quando eu instalo esses módulos ficam visíveis apenas para versão anterior.

Antes da 2.7.10 eu estava com a 2.7.9 e acontecia o mesmo problema.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Comment: Acho que o que está ocorrendo é que o `pip` que está sendo utilizado está carregando o Python errado, possivelmente `/usr/bin/python` que deve ser um symlink para a versão antiga. Use `ls -l /usr/bin/python` para ver se é realmente isso. Se for basta você refazer o symlink para o seu Python novo.

Answer (score 1):

Você provavelmente tem duas instalações do Python — a 2.7.6 deve ser a que veio com a sua distribuição do Linux, e a 2.7.10, que eu imagino que você instalou à mão, em algum canto tipo `/usr/local/`?

Você pode usar o [virtualenv](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52/como-usar-o-virtualenv-para-gerenciar-as-depend%C3%AAncias-duma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-python) pra gerenciar as várias instalações — é o método ideal, na realidade — mas se você quiser fazer algo porco, é só você usar

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m pip
```

ao invés de `pip` sempre que você for instalar um pacote; isso vai garantir que ele vai ser instalado no python 2.7.10, não no python 2.7.6.

Comment: Eu não encontrei nada no local, provavelmente eu tenha lá outra versão sim, mas não teria uma forma de excluir a versão 2.6 e deixar como default do meu sistema a 2.7.10 ?

Comment: Aparentemente a resposta é [“sim”](https://renoirboulanger.com/blog/2015/04/upgrade-python-2-7-9-ubuntu-14-04-lts-making-deb-package/), mas envolve um certo trabalho (e eu faria um backup das suas coisas importantes antes de tentar).

Comment: +1 para o uso de Virtualenv. A menos que você esteja configurando um servidor dedicado, o mais simples de se fazer e manter é utilizar Virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

S e o seu sistema veio com Python 2.7, é possível mante-lo com Python 2.7.10.  e o seu sistema veio com Python 2.6, não dá para mudar o Python padrãodo sistema para 2.7: você vai destruir seu sistema - a maioria das distribuições Linux tem vários programas chave para administração que dependem fortemente do Python no sistema.

A maneira correta de proceder é: usar o gerenciador do sistem apra baixar os pré-requisitos para compilar o Python  (por exemplo, em Debian, Ubuntu e derivados: "apt-get build-dep python-2.7", em fedora: yum-builddep python2). -Baixe o código fonte (o arquivo .tar.gz) de Python.org, e compile uma versão local, para o usuário - configure o prefixo para ser dentro de seu próprio Home (./configure --prefix=/home/usuario/usr) ou um prefixo de sistema, **separado** do `/usr` - `/opt` é uma boa pedida. A vantagem de usar um prefixo dentro do seu /home é não precisar em nenhum momento de permissões de super-usuário (`sudo`) para instalar a nova versão do Python.

Daí, instale o pacote virtualenv no Python do sistema, e para cada projeto em que for trabalhar, crie um virtualenv, usando o Python que voce compilou - para isso use o argumento `-p` do virtualenv. 
Cada vez que for trabalhar no projeto, ative o virtualenv. A sequência, depois de compilado o Python novo, é essa:

```
apt-get install python-virtualenv
virtualenv -p /home/usuario/usr/bin/python-2.7 meuprojeto
cd meuprojeto
source bin/activate
```

e a partir daí coloque os .py do seu novo projeto dentro da pasta  - e instale outros módulos a vontade com o comando `pip`: 
os módulos instalados estarão restritos ao virtualenv. Um segundo projeto que use versões diferentes dos mesmos módulos pode ser criado em outra pasta, e um projeto não vai interferir no outro.

(O passo `source bin/activate` deve ser executado em cada shell que você for executar programas de Python desse projeto - há pacotes auxiliares do virtualenv que permitem um comando mais simples para ativar os virtualenvs,  mas a diferença é quase que só cosmética)

Essa receita funciona da mesmíssima forma para versões mais recentes de Python - e você pode inclusive ter virtualenvs separados com Python 3.4 e Python 3.5 beta.