# Problema para instalar RPM no Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Estou tentando instalar alguns pacotes *RPM* no meu *Ubuntu*, mas estou recebendo mensagens de falhas de dependência. O estranho é que todas as dependências já estão instaladas em meu *SO*.

Criei um diretório `deps` com 4 rpm: `eventlet-0.17.1-1.noarch.rpm`, `greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64.rpm`, `pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64.rpm`, `pyparsing-2.0.3-1.noarch.rpm`.

Executei o seguinte comando:

`sudo rpm -ivh *.rpm`

Obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by eventlet-0.17.1-1.noarch
>   libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64
>   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64
>   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64
>   libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64
>   libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64
>   libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64
>   python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64 rtld(GNU_HASH)
>   is needed by greenlet-0.4.5-1.x86_64 libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by
>   pycrypto-2.6.1-2.x86_64 python(abi) = 2.7 is needed by
>   pyparsing-2.0.3-1.noarch

A primeira dependência que é requerida é o *Python 2.7*, mas quando executo `python --version`, obtenho `Python 2.7.6`.

Alguma ideia de qual é o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E por que você quer instalar pacotes RPM no seu Ubuntu?

Não faça isso - instale os pacotes nativos do Ubuntu de algum repositório apropriado - caso você precise de alguma biblioteca Python que por acaso não esteja nos repositórios do Ubuntu, a melhor coisa a fazer é criar um [virtualenv](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52/como-usar-o-virtualenv-para-gerenciar-as-depend%C3%AAncias-duma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-python) de Python, e instalar a biblioteca lá com `pip install ...`

Pacotes Linux como ".deb" e ".rpm" não são apenas "o programa e os arquivos necessários" - eles são "o programa e os arquivos necessários" cuidadosamente arranjados com metadados para que as dependências do programa sejam encontradas, que os arquivos fiquem em pastas consistentes com as demais pastas do seu sistema, e, por fim, de forma que o sistema saiba gerenciar todos os arquivos instalados como parte de cada pacote para poder gerenciar corretamente as versões dos pacotes.

Um "rpm" é um arquivo feito para uma distribuição Linux diferente do Ubuntu (e mesmo um .deb para outras distribuições poderia ter os mesmos problemas) - e independente de você ter ferramentas que podem "abrir e instalar" o rpm, vão acontecer no mínimo problemas como o acima - no seu caso, um dos sistemas "vê" o Python 2.7.6 e outro "vê" Python 2.7 (em termos de compatibilidade e de bibliotecas os dois sãos o mesmo).

Agora, todos esses pacotes que você menciona são projetos bem conhecidos e bastante usados na comunidade Python - e certamente você só precisa digitar 
`apt-get install python-eventlet python-greenlet python-crypto python-pyparsing`  para que o seu sistema busque esses pacotes *e as dependências* automaticamente na internet. E, quando algum deles for atualizado, as atualizações automáticas do seu sistema ainda vão dar conta disso também.

Agora, lembre-se do `virtualenv` - enquanto você estiver só experimentando, ok usar pacotes do sistema operacional - se estiver começando um projeto de software que use essas bibliotecas, o uso do virtualenv é altamente recomendado - pois permite que você fixe as versões das bibliotecas Python que funcionam para você, independente das versões usadas pelo seu sistema, e isso é replicável em outras máquinas com Linux, independente das versões também.